# Is MySQL's trigger concurrent?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Can there be two triggers running at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This depends mainly on the kind of operation you are running. If table locks of some kind would prevent your second query from execution, its trigger gets delayed as well - thus preventing concurrency.

Comment: It is possible but it depends on quite a few things. Let's say your queries didn't block each other and both issued a trigger (rarely enough event, if you ask me) then you would have to consider the trigger's action as well - does it create a lock of some sort?

The short answer is: it is possible but happens very rarely.